# Software/utility to completely erase cookies/cache

Tags: macbook-pro, software-recommendation, disk-utility, macos

What software (or using any other in-built tools) can I use to clear (by clear, I mean scrub from the disk) the cache & cookies in browsers, without affecting the bookmarks etc. I use firefox 4.

Does deleting them from the browser and running disk util to write zeros on the free space do the trick? Also, this is a shared laptop, so not much chance of drastic steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a free (or paid) utility to do it for you.

[Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/) is a free one that does the job, you have an option to clear your browser's different values:

[image]

[Cocktail](http://www.maintain.se/cocktail/index.php) is a paid ($14.95) nice utility too, that does what Onyx does and the UI is a little bit more elegant and give you some more flexibility:

[image: Cocktail]

Of course, you will have to make sure that you securely empty your thrash if you really want to make sure nobody has access to deleted stuff.

Cocktail has a nice option that may interest you in this regard:

[image]

…which should cover your secure concerns :)

(if OnyX has a secure delete, I couldn't find it in the preferences).

Comment: Do these clean Firefox cookies which are not in ~/Library/Cookies ?

Comment: @Mark I cannot confirm that at the moment, but I'll test (I have Cocktail).

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Cocktail](http://www.maintain.se/cocktail/index.php) for many years and I am quite happy with it. It has many other useful features.